# XSLT Transform failed: 0x80004005 : Type Mismatch UrlDirName

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I get the following error in SharePoint Designer design mode when I add a thumbnail field to a `xsltlistviewwebpart`

Any ideas on how to avoid?

In addition, i want to modify the output of the thumbnail column to have a different **href** than the one by default with SharePoint.

Comment: Give us a sample of the XSLT generated when you add the thumbnail field. Modifying the thumbnail image is quite straightforward in XSL if we can fix this error.